# Wifi connection: I get an IP but can't reach any sites

Tags: networking, wireless, dns, vpn

I suspect a VPN application from Mullvad may have broken some network configuration settings. My system hung while I was using it, and after restarting, I can connect to networks over WiFi and get an IP via DHCP, but I can't access or ping any websites by their domain names. I do get ping response from my router, and from 8.8.8.8, so it seems like it's just domain name resolution that's broken. But I went into my wifi settings and told it to use 8.8.8.8 as the DNS, and I still can't get anywhere.

What can I do from here?

EDIT: I think I've found the root of the problem. It appears that every time NetworkManager sets up a network connection, it's setting the DNS server in /etc/resolv.conf to 127.0.1.1. How do I stop it from doing this?

Comment: Can you ping 8.8.8.8 from your box? What is the output of     cat /etc/resolv.conf     ? What is the output of     ip a    ?

Comment: try "nslookup ubuntu.com" to see if dns works

Comment: I can ping 8.8.8.8, but nslookup cant reach Ubuntu.com.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you reconfigure resolvconf:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
```

Say yes to "prepare /etc/resolve.conf for dynamic updates?" and reboot.

Is there any improvement?

Comment: Nothing changed. I’ve also tested network over Ethernet, and it’s the same, I can ping up addresses but no names resolve.